# v option in /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf

Tags: shell-script, centos, tmp

While checking the file `/tmp.conf` i found option v as 
`v /tmp 1777 root root 10d`
after while read the manual offline and online in 
but i didn't find any thing related, is their any manuals related ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The freedesktop manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html) says:

> `v`
>   Create a subvolume if the path does not exist yet, the file system supports subvolumes (btrfs), and the system itself is installed into a subvolume (specifically: the root directory / is itself a subvolume). Otherwise, create a normal directory, in the same way as d. A subvolume created with this line type is not assigned to any higher-level quota group. For that, use q or Q, which allow creating simple quota group hierarchies, see below.

The intent, as far as I gather, is to make sure that `/tmp` does not enforce disk quotas. (In the now-usual case of `/tmp` being a tmpfs ram disk, it would likely not help anyway, since a user's file quota limit is likely larger than the maximal size of a tmpfs.)